# How to find out which cordinates are closest?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wondering how can I calculate my coordinates to an array of coordinates and find out which one is closest?

Lets say:

```js
var player = {
  x: 10,
  y: 20
}

var box = [
  {x: 17, y: 30},
  {x: 41, y: 14},
  {x: 20, y: 30}
];
```

So my player stays on 10, 20. And i have 3 different boxed, and i need to find out which one is closest. Is there any easy way to caluculate that?

Comment: You can probably use math hey. http://www.mathwarehouse.com/algebra/distance_formula/index.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could calculate the distance and reduce the array by checking each distance and return the object with the shortest.

```js
function getDistance(p1, p2) {
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(p1.x - p2.x, 2) + Math.pow(p1.y - p2.y, 2))
}

var player = { x: 10, y: 20 },
    box = [{ x: 17, y: 30 }, { x: 41, y: 14 }, { x: 20, y: 30 }];

console.log(box.reduce((a, b) => getDistance(a, player) < getDistance(b, player) ? a : b));
```

Comment: Why you are giving an answer of duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24791010/how-to-find-the-coordinate-that-is-closest-to-the-point-of-origin

Comment: i didn't know, but it is an answer with some overhead.

Answer (score 2):

To find the least distance (the closest point) just find the least difference in the sum of the squares of their x and y offsets. You don't need to take the square root to find the actual distance as per Pythagorous's theorom. If you have trouble *writing the code* don't forget to include what you have tried.

Comment: I think this should be a comment not an answer.

Comment: @Zze it answers the question "how to". It doesn't write code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 points canvas formla and sort it based on distance

```js
let positions = [
  {x: 17, y: 30},
  {x: 41, y: 14},
  {x: 20, y: 30}
];

let x=10;
let y= 20;

let positions_close=positions.sort(p=>Math.hypot(p.x-x, p.y-y));

console.log(positions_close[0]);

//check the distance
let distances=positions.map(p=>Math.hypot(p.x-x, p.y-y));
console.log(distances);
```