# Get the id of the nearest coordinate object

Tags: javascript

I am using the [answer in the example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24791010/how-to-find-the-coordinate-that-is-closest-to-the-point-of-origin) to find the nearest object coordinate. How do I find the `index` of the nearest point from `var points` if e.g. the nearest point is `{x: 12, y: 18}`, then `index = 1`?

I want to avoid using an extra **indexOf()** if that step can be saved.The code is:

```
var points = [
  {x: 10, y: 20},
  {x: 12, y: 18},
  {x: 20, y: 30},
  {x: 5, y: 40},
  {x: 100, y: 2}
];

function d(point) {
  return Math.pow(point.x, 2) + Math.pow(point.y, 2);
}

var closest = points.slice(1).reduce(function(min, p) {
  if (d(p) < min.d) min.point = p;
  return min;
}, {point: points[0], d:d(points[0])}).point;

console.log(closest);
```

Comment: What `id` means? I see only coordinates...

Comment: where is your origin?

Comment: Also, in the reducer, you're always comparing the points to the first point in the array because you never change the `d` property of the accumulator, I'm not sure if that is your intention.

Comment: Am I somewhat clearer now @Titus. Sorry, if I put it wrong previously

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could map the array to an array of objects first that also contain the index:

```js
const points = [
  {x: 10, y: 20},
  {x: 12, y: 18},
  {x: 20, y: 30},
  {x: 5, y: 40},
  {x: 100, y: 2}
];

const distance = (point) => {
  return Math.pow(point.x, 2) + Math.pow(point.y, 2);
}

const result = points
     .map((point, index) => ({ point, index }))
     .reduce((a, b) => distance(a.point) < distance(b.point) ? a : b);
     
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Sorry for the edit, just wanted to make it runnable, but instead changed the code a little (removed target, because it wasn't there in the original function) and only realized after I hit apply. If you think it's against your intent, feel free to revert it :)